# SOLVED - How to get row values from XML file in a PHP foreach loop?

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I'm working with a fairly simple xml file (originally displayed as a table) and I need to read the values within each 'row' element (eg. the strings 'fail', '12345'...), but I don't know how to write the correct syntax.
Here is my xml file ($ptpXml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResultList  name='PTP'>
<row status='fail' id='12345' ang='0.0' pr='-18.5'/>/>
<row status='pass' id='54321' ang='0.0' pr='21.3'/>/>
</ResultList>
```

As of now, my code looks like this:

```
/** @var \SC\Core\SimpleXMLElement */
$ptpXml = simplexml_load_file($ptpXml, '\SC\Core\SimpleXMLElement');

foreach ($ptpXml as $idx => $item) { 
    echo $item->status . '<br>';
    echo $item->id . '<br>';
    echo $item->ang . '<br>';
    echo $item->pr . '<br>';
}
```

I've tried multiple options such as:

```
                $test = $item->row->status;
                $test = $item->status;
                $test = $ptpXml->status;
                $test = $ptpXml->row->status;
```

But none of them worked. Sometimes it recongnizes $test as a xml object, but not as the string 'fail'. What am I doing wrong?

===============================================================
**Edit:**
After a lot of testing and some reading, I managed to sort it out! It will look something like this:
Code:

```
/** @var \SC\Core\SimpleXMLElement */
$ptpXml = simplexml_load_file($ptpXml, '\SC\Core\SimpleXMLElement');
...

foreach ($ptpXml as $key => $result) {
   $rows = $result->attributes();
   echo $rows->status . '<br>';
   echo $rows->ang . '<br>';
   ...
}
```

With that the code loops through both rows and I am free to choose from my 'row' element whatever attributes I'd like to work with.

Comment: Using single quotes in `echo '$item->status . <br>';` will also cause a problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: Yeah, that was just an example, it's not how it's actually in my code, sorry about the typo.